# How can I save and switch between multiple display and audio configurations in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, tv

I connected my PC to my TV so that I can play some games on the big screen with an Xbox controller, console style. My video card only allows 2 of its 3 outputs enabled at a time, which are currently used by my two monitors. I want to be able to quickly switch to an alternate configuration, whereby one or both of my monitors are disabled and both audio and primary video are re-routed via HDMI to the TV.

I can do it via the NVIDIA control panel, but the transition is kind of clunky and takes several steps both directions. I tried creating a new Windows user account for the gaming configuration (which would be ideal, since I could also disable interrupting apps like chat and updates) but it seems that such configurations carry across user sessions. Now I've just found that the *Windows-P* shortcut gets me halfway there if I choose "Computer Only" by using the TV as the only display, but I still have to change the audio device*. I'd really like to have a one-step solution so I don't have to keep managing it manually.

**I discovered this partial solution while typing up this question, and so now my question may be "Can I associate an audio configuration with a display configuration automatically?" but I don't want to create an XY problem.*

Comment: Maybe you are still interested in an AutoIt solution? [This one is for toggling sound](http://superuser.com/questions/201973/easy-way-to-switch-default-sound-output-device/540098#540098)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a script to switch default audio devices, such as Toggle Audio 7, and associate it with a hotkey (using AutoIt or AutoHotkey). That would get you there with two steps.

http://flexxcom.nl/2011/03/toggle-audio-7/

Comment: Thanks. Looking into AHK, it seems I can script the whole thing and assign it to a hotkey.