# How to extract the name of the current default audio device via cmd on win10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, audio, cmd.exe

I would like to write a single batch-file which toggles my default sound device, since i only use two.

I'm already using nircmd to set the default device but I have not found a way to extract the name of the current device.

Comment: This may be helpful / related https://superuser.com/questions/1054594/switching-default-audio-device-with-a-batch-file

Comment: @Dave Actually from this thread i got the "how to set" but not "how to get" the name of the device

Comment: And does entering `driverquery` into a cmd contain what you want?

Comment: Does this powershell do it? See last post https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/003f3047-43dd-4390-a048-befbf8af58eb/command-line-to-list-out-every-devices-name-driver-provider-and-driver-version?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: @Dave Ideally I want the same name which it has in sound control, because thats what nircmd expects, i will look into the script

Comment: Ok so its the same name, but i dont see a way to determine if it is listed as the default device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I have not found a way to extract the name of the current audio device.

If you don't mind using PowerShell then try `Get-DefaultAudioDevice` from [Powershell Cmdlets for manipulating Windows Audio Devices](https://github.com/cdhunt/WindowsAudioDevice-Powershell-Cmdlet):

> Basic command-line audio device control from Powershell including Nuget Package Manager Console.
>
> Features: Set Volume and toggle Mute on the Default Playback Device. Get a list of devices and set the Default Audio Device.

...

> Exposed Cmdlets
>
> ```
> Get-DefaultAudioDevice
> Get-AudioDeviceList
> Set-DefaultAudioDevice [-Index] <Int>
> Set-DefaultAudioDevice [-Name] <String>
> Set-DefaultAudioDevice [-InputObject] <AudioDevice>
> Set-DefaultAudioDeviceVolume -Volume <float>
> Get-DefaultAudioDeviceVolume
> Set-DefaultAudioDeviceMute <Bool>
> Set-DefaultAudioDeviceMute #Toggle
> Get-DefaultAudioDeviceMute
> Write-DefaultAudioDeviceValue [-StreamValue]
> ```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, will try that out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SoundVolumeView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) to dump your audio devices into a CSV file and then parse it using cut and grep:

```
SoundVolumeView.exe /scomma dump.csv
cut dump.csv -d',' -f1,5|grep ',Render'|cut -d',' -f1
```

Unfortunately it doesn’t seem to support stdout so it’s necessary to write to a file.

Column 1 contains the device name, column 5 is the column named "Default" and contains either "Render" or "Capture" (or nothing). If you have changed the column order in the GUI, you have to change the indices. Better than fixed indices would be to parse the first line looking for the column headers "Name" and "Default".

As for cut and grep, I use the programs included in [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/). If you dont’t want to install Git, you could use [gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki). They are also included in [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) and [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), but those haven’t been updated for years.

Answer (score 0):

```
SoundVolumeView.exe /scomma exit.csv
for /f "tokens=4 delims=, skip=1" %%a in (exit) do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"%CD%\SOUNDVOLUMEVIEW\SoundVolumeView.exe" /scomma "%CD%\SOUNDVOLUMEVIEW\Audio.txt"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%d in ('type "%EXTRA%\SOUNDVOLUMEVIEW\Audio.txt" ^| find "Capture,Capture"') do set "INPUTDEVICE=%%d"
echo Default audio input device is: "%INPUTDEVICE%"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ('type "%CD%\SOUNDVOLUMEVIEW\Audio.txt" ^| find "Render,Render"') do set "OUTPUTDEVICE=%%a"
echo Default audio output device is: "%OUTPUTDEVICE%"
```

Copy this script into a batch file inside the SoundVolumeView directory. It puts the current audio input and output devices into the variables "%INPUTDEVICE%" and "%OUTPUTDEVICE%" respectively.

I hope this helps!