# .bat script to change audio outputs?

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, batch-file

As my Windows machine is hooked up to 2 different tvs in 2 separate rooms, I  am constantly having to change the audio outputs in the Windows sound preferences. I am hoping to find a way, either with a .bat script or other means to speed up the process, or even automate it. A hardware solution would be acceptable as well.

The audio is sent out via two separate outputs:
1---> onboard 8th inch jack to mixer
2---> wireless HMDI to Sony amp.

Here are the 2 outputs as seen in Windows Sound Preferences:
[image]

Is there a Windows command to enable/disable specific sound devices that I could use in  a.bat script? If so, is there a way to automate this based on which TV is turned on? Iimagine I would need to know some kind of device ID to include in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply - I just came here since Google showed the question. I found a nice solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1054594/switching-default-audio-device-with-a-batch-file#answer-1054794) - maybe it'll help future visitors ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution, but it is a solution nevertheless, so that's why I'm posting this.

Actual Tools has a program that can do this. It can redirect audio on a per-program based, depending on what monitor the program is. So you can set it so that if you move a window from one screen to the other, it will change audio settings to output audio to another screen.

I have Actual Tools Windows Manager which is the total suite, but there is also one specifically for this feature. I only don't know which one of them this has, but their site has all the features listed.

The only downside is that this is not a free product. But you buy a licence that works for life, and you get a year of free updates.

If you really don't want to throw money at it, then the easiest solution would be to upgrade to windows 10. In windows 10, you can simply click the speaker in the system tray, then click on the soundcard dropdown button and select a different audio device to switch.

As for Automation, I bet Nircmd (from Nirsoft.net) can do this, but I have no experience with it.