# Windows alarm on wrong audio device

Tags: windows, audio, tv, alarm

I use a TV as my second monitor, I want to have an alarm that rings on my tv(really loud), I configured on BIOS for my Laptop to turn on 5 minutes before the time configured on windows alarm, but when it turns on it rings on my headphones and not on my tv, but my tv is enabled as my default sound device, I tried run this command `nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "LG TV" 1` on startup and common startup but it didn't worked, what should I do?

OS: Windows 10

Alarm application: Windows 10 default one

Comment: Which application is used for the alarm?

Comment: @harrymc The default windows application for alarms

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a solution for it.

Comment: According to this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/1054594/switching-default-audio-device-with-a-batch-file), Nircmd is a 3rd party software that must be installed to use the command you tried.  Some other ideas to try: Settings > Sound > Advanced sound options > App Volume and device preferences allows you to choose which sound device you want a particular app to use.  Alarm may not appear as its' own device though and you may need to use the generic "System sounds", but it may give you the opportunity to assign other apps to your tv, like games, video players or web browsers.