# Pipe microphone's input to an output device

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, microphone

I'm working on a soundboard software (using VB-Audio Virtual Cable)

I need to pipe the input coming from a specific audio **input** device (not default) to a specific **output** device with CMD or PowerShell (so it can be done programmatically)

I've tried using ffmpeg and ffplay, but I couldn't get them working

### Edit

I've managed to achieve the desired behavior just from Windows setting

[image]

Now I just want a way to do it programmatically (automatically)

Comment: Post an FFmpeg command that records your "microphone" device into an audio file. Post FFplay command that plays an audio file to your audio output device. Configuring a pipe may be simple.

Comment: I figured the ffmpeg part, but I couldn't find how to select the output device with ffplay

Comment: I also couldn't find it. I think we can't select the output device with FFplay.

Comment: @Rotern, have you managed to do it with some other tool?

Comment: No, but the [following post](https://superuser.com/questions/1054594/switching-default-audio-device-with-a-batch-file) shows how to change the default audio device using command line.