# Is there a way to quickly switch between two audio inputs without using the command line?

Tags: windows-10

I've got like 9 audio outputs in the toolbox menu but I only use 2 of them 90% of the time. Two of the nine are named "Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)" so that's super unhelpful. Ideally I'd have a quick audio switcher that's just the two "favorite" devices. Is there any way to do this? It's much easier on a Mac...

I don't want to use command line for this. Ideally it would be something in the toolbar that just has a few available "favorite" audio options. There is already something in the toolbar for this so command line is worse than that.

Comment: Form https://superuser.com/questions/1054594/switching-default-audio-device-with-a-batch-file : you can use third-party Nircmd ,e.g., `nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Line in"`, or the PowerShell script in that answer. See also https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setdefaultsounddevice.html

Comment: You can apply commands/scripts to icons/shortcuts that can be placed in convenient locations. So the duplicate still stands.

Comment: The actual answer here is much better. That question doesn't discuss how to do it without the command line so it's an incomplete answer for my question. I don't see the harm in having two slightly different questions.

Comment: I appreciate that the answer presented here may better suit your needs, but besides the points already made, the answer posted here currently a low quality "link only" answer, because it does not explain how to use the tool suggested to solve your problem, counter to the rules for this site and the recommendations found in the help section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use a third-party program, [**Audioswitcher**](https://audioswit.ch/er) does exactly what you want.

The great thing about this is that you can favorite a couple of devices and use the  app tray to switch them with a right-click. This is much better than using a command line tool. And it's free.

[image: Sample image here].

**To set up a hotkey for a playback/recording device:**

1. Right click on the playback recording device
2. Select `Set hotkey`

[image]

3. Mimic the hotkey you want to set

[image]

**To add an playback/recording device to favourite**, right click on the device and select `favourite device`. Devices added to favourites appear in   the popup menu when the tray icon of the app is right clicked.

**Additionally**, you can also check `close to tray`, `start when windows starts` and `start minimised` from the **settings tab** as per requirement.

[image]

Comment: Looks like exactly what I want.

Comment: This is currently a link only answer. Please include information about HOW to use the product you're suggesting to solve OPs problem to make this a valuable answer, rather than what it currently is: a suggestive comment.

Comment: @music2myear sorry for the previous link-based answer. I have improved the answer and have demonstrated basic usage of the app.